# Animate recomposition (view changes) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to automatically animate composition changes in a Jetpack Compose `@Composable`? For instance, if a previously shown widget is removed in a recomposition, can a  fade-out animation be applied automatically? I'm thinking something similar to Android `View`'s `animateLayoutChanges`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use:

```
val visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
AnimatedVisibility(visible = visible) {
    // Composables Here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To all folks coming here looking for an alternative to android `View`'s `animateLayoutChanges` or its programmatical counterpart, `LayoutTransition()`, to use with Jetpack Compose and Composable Layouts, there are two main approaches that I have explained below:

**First approach** is to use [`Modifier.animateContentSize()`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedContentSize). There are different parameters that you set to this extension function to customize its animation.

```
var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Column(modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize().clickable { isExpanded = !isExpanded }) {
    Text(text = "This text is always visible!")

    if (isExpanded) {
        Text(text = "This text's visibility is toggled by clicking on the column!")
    }
}
```

**Second approach** would be to wrap part of your layout that would change its visibility, in [`AnimatedVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedvisibility) as shown below:

```
var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Column(modifier = Modifier.clickable { isExpanded = !isExpanded }) {
    Text(text = "This text is always visible!")

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = isExpanded) {
        Text(text = "This text's visibility is toggled by clicking on the column!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi could you please take a look at this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041928/animatelayoutchanges-doesnt-work-when-using-compose-in-linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Or for the specific animation you asked for, surround the Composable (s) with `CrossFade`