# [Compose+View]animateLayoutChanges doesn't work when using compose in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I am migrating the existing View to Compose, `animateLayoutChanges` is enabled for the parent LinearLayout to layout transition animation. But the animation doesn't work for the ComposeView. The the xml layout is:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dls_space_2x"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
                android:id="@+id/first_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/second_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/third_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```